# Jface ViewerFilter filtering full tree depth

Tags: eclipse, jface

I have a FilteredTree that displays many nodes, where each node can have multiple children and subchildren (n-depth).

The filter filters all nodes (and children in any depth) that match the pattern.

Now I want to add another search functionality:

Every node represent an object , each object has some fields, so i want to list the nodes that have fields that match the text.

I tired to use ViewerFilter.

The problem with it that it doesn't invoked for every node in the tree only for current opened branch.

```
public class TheFilter extends ViewerFilter {

          private String searchString;

          public void setSearchText(String s) {

          }


          public boolean select(Viewer viewer, 
              Object parentElement, 
              Object element) { //triggered Only for one level


            return true;
          }
        }
```

Update:

When the searched item is found I want to show not just that node that contains the searched item but also it's parent (all parents).

Answer (score 1):

`FilteredTree` accepts an `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PatternFilter` as argument to determine it's filter strategy.

You can achieve the desired result by subclassing PatternFilter and overriding it's `isLeafMatch` method.

For example:

```
PatternFilter filter = new PatternFilter() {
    @Override
    protected boolean isLeafMatch(Viewer viewer, Object element) {
        String field = ((Node) element).getField();
        if(field== null) {
            return false;
        }
        return wordMatches(field);
    }
};
FilteredTree tree = new FilteredTree(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL, filter, true);
```

Comment: This is not recursive method... so it won't search the complete tree.

As I tried to explain in my question, I can't use the filter Feature for this search because I already use it to filter the tree by labels. And I can't apply 2 filters on one tree

Comment: Also I can't use one filter for both searches because it will be an overkill

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, you need a `FilteredTree` with two textboxes, one filtering based on element labels and one based on element fields?

Comment: This method will search for leafs which match the filter. To expand this to all nodes in the tree you have to also override the `isParentMatch` method.

Comment: the answer is yes for your first question.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want the search to be applied to all elements regardless of the fact that they are currently expanded or not. Although I am not sure why would you want the filtering to applied to the deepest leaf as well, is it because you want root nodes that will not show any children to disappear as well?

There could be several ways here, if you want to force your filter to be applied to all elements, you can expand all items in the tree using `TreeViewer#expandAll`, unless you are using a lazy content provider it should invoke filtering on all elements. You may collapse the tree again if you don't want to keep it expanded (may want to disable drawing while expanding and collapsing to avoid flicker through `Tree#setRedraw(boolean)`). Usually in trees when something is being searched, all filtered content is shown as expanded so that the deepest leaf that also matches the search criteria is also visible. If you want to maintain tree's expansion states of each element just as the user had done, it will require a little more work to expand all and then restore expansions.

Another approach is to implement the searching within the content provider. So your content provider can take the current search criterion and return only elements that match it. This means that you will have to manage yourself whether a certain parent should be visible or not. So on change of search field you only need to refresh tree and your content provider will ensure filtering.

Comment: I am not using lazy content provider, I want to show in the tree only the leafs that match the search pattern, and ofcourse all the parents of those leafs till the root. I think if I do expandall i will see the unwanted effect (all tree is expanded and visible)

Comment: As I stated, I don't want to use FilteredTree with "PatternFilter" for that search, FilteredTree is used to filter the labels.

Comment: If you want the filtering to affect parents in such a way that if all children are hidden the parent should be as well, then you will have to do this manually. The tree viewer does not do this automatically it will filter each element individually. So if you want to use an additional ViewerFilter your filter logic should take care of hiding parents whose all children will be hidden. If your logic can handle this than you won't need your filter to be called recursively to the deepest leaf.